# Wordpress Facebook Feed plugin display bug

Tags: wordpress, plugins, display

I'm working with Wordpress, and i'm searching a issue for my problem, I'm using Ceevee's theme, and a plugin for feeds from social network (Facebook Feed).
But I have problem with displaying of feeds.
I have some Screenshot for show you :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REmvI.png)

And When I'm resizing the window, regardless the size of window, the display transform and become like i want.
Trying on firefox and chrome, and result is same

Here code:

```
<div id="socialcolumn1">
<div id="socialfeed570">[socialfeed id='570']</div>
</div>
<div id="socialcolumn2">
<div id="socialfeed571">[socialfeed id='571']</div>
</div>
<div id="socialcolumn3">
<div id="socialfeed572">[socialfeed id='572']</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#socialcolumn1{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: auto;
}
#socialcolumn2{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: auto;
margin-left: 196px;
}
#socialcolumn3{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: auto;
margin-left: 196px;
}
```

I think this is problem on loading of tab / tile, but i don't know how fix this :( I was ask the support's plugin, but no issue.

If you want more screen, ask me, i can't post more 1 link per post :/
Thanks !